# postfix, send to gmail, yahoo, not working

Tags: postfix

I've setup a postfix on Ubuntu 16.04 that appears to not work as it supposed.
Receive works, I use mail and able to see gmail, yahoo emails just fine.

YAHOO says:

```
said: 553 5.7.1
[BL21] Connections will not be accepted from xx.xx.xx.xx., because the ip
is in Spamhaus's list;
```

But I've already checked and there is no problem with blacklists (mxtoolbox.com find none now)

GMAIL server keep saying:

```
The IP you're using to send mail is not
    authorized to 550-5.7.1 send email directly to our servers. Please use the
    SMTP relay at your 550-5.7.1 service provider instead.
```

Why is that? I'm not on any black list or whatever.
I'm able to receive from GMAIL just fine.

Also, I own that IP and reverse DNS is OK.

The http://mxtoolbox.com reports just this:

```
dmarc   xxxxxx.com  Record Missing   More Info
spf     xxxxxx.com  No records found     More Info
dns     xxxxxx.com  SOA Expire Value out of recommended range
```

And my DNS settings are

```
a   @   xx.xx.xx.xx     600 seconds     Edit
cname   *   @   600 seconds     Edit
cname   www     @   1 Hour  Edit
mx  0   @ (Priority: 0)     600 seconds     Edit
txt     @   "v=spf1 mx a -all"  600 seconds     Edit
ns  @   ns73.domaincontrol.com  1 Hour  
ns  @   ns74.domaincontrol.com  1 Hour
```

UPDATE: I've created a new account to mail.com and this time worked.

So seems that gmail and yahoo are not working, perhaps need some extra parameters (security) or whatever?

Answer (score 1):

You will get better help if you don't obfuscate your data.  Google and Yahoo don't readily accept email from servers that don't follow standards and best practices.  I would suggest adding DKIM and DMARC to your settings.

Your DNS entries don't look right.  Try querying ns73.domaincontrol.com for your DNS records.  I've  listed what may be the correct data for bind.

```
@   a    xx.xx.xx.xx
    txt  "v=spf1 mx a -all"        
    ns   ns73.domaincontrol.com.
    ns   ns75.domaincontrol.com.

www a    xx.xx.xx.xx
    txt  "v=spf1 mx a -all"        

mail a   xx.xx.xx.xx
     txt  "v=spf1 a -all"
```

See [Fighting Spam - What can I do as an: Email Administrator, Domain Owner, or User?](https://serverfault.com/questions/419407/fighting-spam-what-can-i-do-as-an-email-administrator-domain-owner-or-user) for some more data.  I've posted several block entries on email starting with [Running a Mail Server](https://www.systemajik.com/blog/running-an-email-server/).

Comment: I just cannot publish customer IP. Problem solved partially, both yahoo and gmail receive emails but SPF is detected unset no matter what I do.

Comment: @user1797147 If SPF is detected as unset by Yahoo and Gmail, then it is.  This may be due to cached DNS data, but is likely your DNS configuration.  Try `host -a example.com 8.8.8.8` using your customer's domain in place of `example.com`.  Once SPF shows up there, then Gmail and Yahoo will soon start seeing the SPF data.  Set SPF for both the mail servers domain, and the domain in the sending address.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I spent all night to solve but at GoDaddy there are no SPF records. I could only set a TXT one and no matter what I put there, yahoo sais no SPF. Perhaps caching or something else is wrong.

Comment: Also struggled for DMARC but seems that these are also quite hard to set. No clear info how to set them. What is curiouse is that I use dig to inspect others DNS and mine are the same.

Comment: @user1797147  Get SPF and DKIM working before you try DMARC, DMARC needs both working.

Answer (score 0):

@BillThor Thanks a lot!

While investigating more, I found a really stupid issue that is not explained at GoDaddy's interface and I probably followed several tutorials on internet:

**!!! For GoDaddy domains, don't use double quotes while enter your TXT records in DNS manager area !!!**

They will add their quotes which will result in a escaped string that will make to fail your SPF and DKIM like mine.

Use

```
dig -t txt domain.com
host -t txt domain.com
```

And both reported me

domain.com descriptive text "\"v=spf1 mx mx:mail.domain.com ip4:xx.xx.xx.xx ~all"\"

which is completely wrong. Enter text AS IS and no more SPF issue on yahoo and the rest:

Received-SPF: pass (domain of domain.com designates xx.xx.... as permitted sender)

Thanks again. I was about to leave as is.